# Angular 16 p-tree component(PrimeNG)

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm having difficulties in rendering custom parent node and its children in PrimeNg Angular 16.

The problem is that I want to have custom behaviour in p-tree component.

I need to for example add a specific icons when some children label is clicked.
Also I want to customize these children labels so they look different from parent node label.

example:

```html
<p-tree [value]="nodes" class="w-full md:w-30rem">
  <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
    <span>{{ node.label }}</span>
    <!----- here I want to render children node label -->
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
    <b>{{ node.label }}</b>
    <!----- here I want to render parent node label  -->
  </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

But I can't target these children label property.

data structure is [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7efU.png)

I tried everything from official documentation of https://primeng.org/tree.